# How do I print all the modules and number of students studying each module in descending oder using these tables?

Tags: sql, sqlite

[image: Image contains tables to be used]

I came across this question and I'm not sure how to solve it.
Help out please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the table `studies` you need to `group by module` and count the number of students (I guess there is no case of a student existing twice for a module):

```
select module, count(student) counter 
from studies
group by module
order by counter desc
```

Comment: Thank you so much buddy!

Comment: Accepted! Thanks again @forpas!